# how I can upload image from android app using to cloud firestore and see it inside the web page

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-storage

I tried to make an Android app using Kotlin and Jetpack Compose.
I have a problem with uploading images in the sign-up operation.
I made the function and handled it by compose and it works just fine, but it keeps uploading the images as an array in my cloud firestore and not a real image it doesn't show any image.
I want to understand where is my problem.

Here is my UI code
not all the code just the necessary

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SignUpScreenWorker(
    signUpWorkerViewModel: SignUpWorkerViewModel = viewModel(),
    navController: NavController,
    context: Context
) {
    val buttonShape = mediumShape
    val imageUri = remember { mutableStateListOf<Uri>() }
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents()) { uris: List<Uri>? ->
        uris?.let {
            imageUri.clear()
            imageUri.addAll(it)
        }
    }

    // all other code 
            // Image Upload Button
            IconButton(
                onClick = {
                    launcher.launch("image/*")
                          // Launch the file picker
                },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 8.dp)
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.AccountBox,
                    contentDescription = null,
                    tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
                )
            }

            // Uploaded Images
            imageUri.forEach { uri ->
                val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(uri)
                Image(
                    painter = painter,
                    contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.img_uri),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(80.dp)
                        .padding(vertical = 8.dp)
                )
            }
            
        }

// all other code 
...

the view model
```

class SignUpWorkerViewModel : ViewModel() {

```
private val firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
private val firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
private val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()

var imgs: List<Uri> by mutableStateOf(emptyList())


fun onSignUpButtonClicked(navController: NavController, context: Context) {
    val imageUris = imgs.toList()
    // all other variables
    
    viewModelScope.launch {

        try {

            // Upload each selected image
            val uploadedImageUrls = imageUris.map { uploadImage(it)
```

// all other variables
}

```
          firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(enteredEmail, 
          enteredPassword)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    val workerDocument = firestore
                        .collection("workers")
                        .document(firebaseAuth.currentUser?.email ?: "")
                    workerDocument
                        .set(
                            hashMapOf(
                                "Image" to uploadedImageUrls,
                                "name" to enteredName,
                                "Address" to enteredAddress,
                                "Number" to enteredNumber
                            )
                        )
                    navController.navigate(DestinationScreen.Terms.name)
                }
                



// Function to upload image to Cloud Storage and get the download URL
suspend fun uploadImage(imageUri: Uri): List<Uri> {
    val storageRef = storage.reference
    val imageRef = storageRef.child("images/${FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid}/${imageUri.lastPathSegment}")
    val uploadTask = imageRef.putFile(imageUri)
    val taskSnapshot = uploadTask.await()
    val downloadUrls = mutableListOf<Uri>()
    downloadUrls.add(taskSnapshot.storage.downloadUrl.await())

    return downloadUrls
}
```

}

i think the problem with the function that upload the image how it upload it and which type, but i cant see the problem.

Comment: There are well over 400 lines of code in your question, without a clear indication where the error occurs. While someone may of course spot the problem and answer, changes of that drastically go up if you take the time to reproduce the problem in isolation from scratch. For more on why this is useful/necessary and how to do this, see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).